# why does $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{e^{x-1}}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{e^x}{2ex}$

Tags: calculus

Why does $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{e^{x-1}}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{e^x}{2ex}$

[image]

I know this is answered here [How to evaluate $ \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{e^{x-1}-1}{x^2-1} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1075574/how-can-you-evaluate-this-limit) 
but I want explain alternative way/wolfram alpha's way too...
can you substitute 1 for x right after l'hopitals rule and not do this $\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{e^{x-1}}{2x}=\frac{\lim_{x\to 1}e^x}{\lim_{x\to 1}2ex}$?
I'm explaining this in class presentation to high school calculus class...

Comment: As the function is defined at 1, then limit is the exact value of the function as the function is continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because in general, $a^{b-1} = a^b/a$.

This fits naively into the "exponentiation is repeated multiplication" heuristic (be that [accurate or not](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/is-it-advisable-to-avoid-teaching-multiplication-as-repeated-addition)).

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there's no need to go through the extra steps. Since $\frac{e^{x-1}}{2x}$ is continuous at $x=1$ (convince yourself of this, from what you know about the properties of continuous functions), you can plug it straight in to find the limit.